# How do I add an extra field with machine name field_caption?

Tags: 7, media

How do I add an extra field with machine name field_caption?

Do I need any module to implement it?

[image]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

My Answer:
Download the following module
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption
https://www.drupal.org/project/insert

Insert settings:
Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » Article » Manage fields
Enable insert button

Upload image in node and add caption in text.

The text will become caption.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why you added that image (without a caption ...) to your question. Maybe there is anything we see in that image that you want to be used as a caption? I bet your question is not something like "How do I add an extra field with machine name field_caption?" And also ***where*** should such caption appear, eg when the node is viewed, in a views slideshow, somewhere else?

Comment: Merci for accepting my suggestion, and even use part of my comments ... While waiting for your question to eventually get reopened, here is an answer (which I might post later on after reopen): go to the content type in admin, then use tab "manage fields", and add that field just there, using whatever specs fit your needs. Done